Local file changes not coming in rootfs using yocto build
I am using poky version 2.4. We are copying a file to rootfs from a local directory(used file in SRC_URI) using bbappend file. I have modified the file in the local directoy and started the build, but my changes in that file is not reflecting.
I have removed the file in the local directory to confirm that the build is taking the file from the local directory or not. In this scenario the build failed saying that file is not available.
Any suggestions to debug it. The build is looking for the file in the local directory as per bbappend SRC_URI, but if we do any changes then it is not reflecting in the rootfs.

Please post your bbappend file
